# How to resolve Promise mismatch in Angular / Typescript app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to retrieve a `User` object from Firestore in my Angular app.

`User` model:

```
import { PlaceLocation } from './location.model';

    export class User {
        constructor(
            public userId: string,
            public userName: string,
            public isMechanic: boolean,
            public location: PlaceLocation
        ) { }
    }
```

Component:

```
user: User;

this.usersService
    .getUserByUserId(paramMap.get('id'))
    .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
});
```

Users Service:

```
getUserByUserId(userId: string) {
    return of(
      firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("userId", "==", userId)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          console.log("Query Snapshot:", querySnapshot);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("Query Error:", err);
        })
    );
  }
```

But I'm getting this compilation error when I try to assign `this.user = user`:

> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type
>   'User': userId, userName, isMechanic, location

Can someone please tell me what changes are required to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're returning an observable of a promise... think you want `from`, which converts a promise into an observable.

```
  getUserByUserId(userId: string) {
    return from(
      firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("userId", "==", userId)
        .get()
    ).pipe(
      map(querySnapshot => { ... do transform ... }),
      tap( // handle errors / logging in observable fashion
        query => console.log(query, 'success),
        error => console.log(error, 'error')
      ),
      // catchError(error => { ... do something with error ... })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my code with your changes, so am getting this error now: `Type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>' is missing the following properties from type 'User': userId, userName, isMechanic, location`

Comment: then your typings are wrong... and you need to fix that. the firestore get() method is returning that QuerySnapshot type, you need to map it into or declare it as the User type you want.

Comment: Is there a way I can map the response data to fit the `User` model I have in my question?

Comment: use the rxjs `map` operator to do a transform of the data.  added example

Answer (score 0):

"from(...promise...)" solution will not always work. Promise could resolve before you soubscribe on.

True way is make observable at first:

```
getUserByUserId(userId: string) {
  return new Observable<any>((observer: Observer<any>) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("userId", "==", userId)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          observer.next(querySnapshot);
          observer.complete();
        }).catch((err) => {
          observer.error(err);
        })

  });
}
```

Comment: not true: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-drqnss?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: if you check the source for `from` it's actually doing mostly this with one or two corner cases covered as well